# Implications of disproving the Goldbach's Conjecture

Tags: examples-counterexamples, goldbachs-conjecture

What would be the most important implications of finding an even number that cannot be expressed as the sum of two primes? Would the existence on one such number in anyway predict the likeliness of any more such numbers?

Moreover, will there be any other theorems that can be proved/disproved because of this?

P.s. The answer to the latter is most likely yes, I just asked that additionally for future reference (for myself and others)

Comment: The Goldbach conjecture is not really famous because it is particularly important -- it's merely because it is _extremely simple to state_, so even people who know quite little mathematics will be able to understand what it states. Arguably it is the simplest unsolved conjecture left after Fermat's last theorem was proved. The twin prime conjecture comes close, but Goldbach is arguably simpler to grasp, because it doesn't require a concept of "infinitely many", merely of "all even numbers".

Comment: @HenningMakholm Collatz conjecture is so easy to understand that even i can understand that.

Comment: @ritwiksinha: Yes, but Goldbach is simpler still. For any given number there's a definite procedure you can follow to find out whether it's a Goldbach counterexample or not. In contrast, it is conceivable that you could have a Collatz counterexample and never be able to know for sure that it is in fact a counterexample.

Comment: @Peter: As far as I know, that is the _weak_ Goldbach conjecture (which is about _odd_ numbers being the sum of _three_ primes). Do you have a reference?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Now, as you say it, I think you are right. I delete my comment.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Oh, yes you are right. It is so funny that such a easy to understand problem can't be solved even after centuries, Goldbach was a genius.

Answer (score 0):

Parts of Goldbach's conjecture failing for 2n:

- 2n-3 isn't prime
- If n is 4 or 1 mod 6, There exists a value of n that has fewer primes congruent to 1 mod 3 less than 2n-3, than there are gaps in that sequence before n.
- If n is 2,5 mod 6, There exists an n value that has fewer primes that are 2 mod 3 less than 2n-3, than gaps in that sequence before n.
- If n is 3,0 mod 6, There exists an n value where The gaps in x mod 3 primes below n is larger than the the number of primes -x mod 3 between n and 2n-3